# JavaScript not throwing ReferenceError when using events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

UPDATE: This issue cannot be reproduced in Chromium. It seems to be specific to Firefox (both developer toolbar and Firebug).
I have tried disabling all add-ons but still can't get the errors to fire. RUnning Firefox 24.1.1 ([mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) tells me I am using the latest version. This behaviour has been consistent across updates.

I am really new to using events in JavaScript so hopefully this is an easy fix. But I couldn't sift through all the "error handling" articles when I search for "javascript custom event handler no errors"

When I execute the following code with a syntax error ("consle.log"; no "o"), it fails without throwing any syntax errors

```
function greetHandler(){
  
  consle.log("Hey bro");
  
}

document.addEventListener("greet", greetHandler,false);
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('greet'));
```

However, if I were to use run only:

```
consle.log("Hey bro");
```

The console would loudly complain:

> ReferenceError: consle is not defined

How can I get that `ReferenceError` throwing when I am using `eventListener`s to make my debugging life easier?

Comment: No repro here on Firefox 29.0.1 for Windows (latest version as of this posting).